# How to load a CSV file into Apache Arrow vectors and save an arrow file to disk

Tags: java, scala, csv, apache-arrow

I'm currently playing with [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/)'s java API (though I use it from Scala for the code samples) to get some familiarity with this tool.

As an exercise, I chose to load a CSV file into arrow vectors and then to save these to an arrow file. The first part seemed easy enough, and I tried it like this:

```
val csvLines: Stream[Array[String]] = <open stream from CSV parser>

// There are other types of allocator, but things work with this one...
val allocator = new RootAllocator(Int.MaxValue)

// Initialize the vectors
val vectors = initVectors(csvLines.head, allocator)
// Put their mutators into an array for easy access
val mutators = vectors.map(_.getMutator)

// Work on the data, zipping it with its index 
Stream.from(0)
  .zip(csvLines.tail) // Work on the tail (head contains the headers)
  .foreach(rowTup =>  // rowTup = (index, csvRow as an Array[String])
    Range(0, rowTup._2.size) // Iterate on each column...
      .foreach(columnNumber =>
        writeToMutator(
          mutators(columnNumber), // get that column's mutator
          idx=rowTup._1,          // pass the current row number
          data=rowTup._2(columnNumber) // pass the entry of the curernt column
        )
      )
)
```

With `initVectors()` and `writeToMutator()` defined as:

```
def initVectors(
  columns: Array[String], 
  alloc: RootAllocator): Array[NullableVarCharVector] = {

  // Initialize a vector for each column
  val vectors = columns.map(colName => 
    new NullableVarCharVector(colName, alloc))
  // 4096 size, for 1024 values initially. This is arbitrary
  vectors.foreach(_.allocateNew(2^12,1024))
  vectors
}

def writeToMutator(
  mutator: NullableVarCharVector#Mutator, 
  idx: Int, 
  data: String): Unit = {

  // The CSV may contain null values
  if (data != null) {
    val bytes = data.getBytes()
    mutator.setSafe(idx, bytes, 0, bytes.length)
  }
  mutator.setNull(idx)
}
```

<sub>(I currently don't care about using the correct type, and store everything as strings, or `VarChar` in arrow's terns)</sub>

So at this point I have a collection of `NullableVarCharVector` and can read and write from/to them. Everything great at this point. Now, for the next step, though, I was left wondering about how to actually wrap them together and serialize them to an arrow file. I stumbled on an `AbstractFieldWriter` abstract class, but how to use the implementations is unclear.

So, the question mainly is:

- what is the (best? – there seem to be multiple ones) way to save a bunch of vectors to an arrow file.
- are there other ways of loading CSV columns to arrow vectors?

**edited to add:** The [metadata description page](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/format/Metadata.md) provides a good general overview on that topic.

<sub>The api's test classes seem to contain a few things that could help, I'll post a reply with a sample once I've tried it out.</sub>

Comment: Semi-related but nonetheless interesting read: https://mapr.com/blog/apache-arrow-and-value-vectors/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [TestArrowFile.java](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/java/vector/src/test/java/org/apache/arrow/vector/ipc/TestArrowFile.java) and [BaseFileTest.java](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/java/vector/src/test/java/org/apache/arrow/vector/ipc/BaseFileTest.java) I found:

- How to write a single arrow file to disk
- An alternate way of filling vectors, as my first attempt prevented me from assembling a single arrow file (or at least to do so in a straightforward manner).

So, filling up vectors now looks like:

```
// Open stream of rows 
val csvLines: Stream[Array[String]] = <open stream from CSV parser>
// Define a parent to hold the vectors
val parent = MapVector.empty("parent", allocator)
// Create a new writer. VarCharWriterImpl would probably do as well?
val writer = new ComplexWriterImpl("root", parent)

// Initialise a writer for each column, using the header as the name
val rootWriter = writer.rootAsMap()
val writers = csvLines.head.map(colName => 
                                  rootWriter.varChar(colName))

Stream.from(0)
  .zip(csvLines.tail) // Zip the rows with their index
  .foreach( rowTup => { // Iterate on each (index, row) tuple
    val (idx, row) = rowTup
      Range(0, row.size) // Iterate on each field of the row
        .foreach(column =>
          Option(row(column)) // row(column) may be null,
            .foreach(str =>   // use the option as a null check
              write(writers(column), idx, allocator, str)
            )
      )
  }
)

toFile(parent.getChild("root"), "csv.arrow") // Save everything to a file
```

with `write` defined as:

```
def write(writer: VarCharWriter, idx: Int, 
  allocator: BufferAllocator, data: String): Unit = {
  // Set the position to the correct index
  writer.setPosition(idx)
  val bytes = data.getBytes()
  // Apparently the allocator is required again to build a new buffer
  val varchar = allocator.buffer(bytes.length)
  varchar.setBytes(0, data.getBytes())
  writer.writeVarChar(0, bytes.length, varchar)
}

def toFile(parent: FieldVector, fName: String): Unit = {
  // Extract a schema from the parent: that's the part I struggled with in the original question
  val rootSchema = new VectorSchemaRoot(parent)
  val stream = new FileOutputStream(fName)
  val fileWriter = new ArrowFileWriter(
                        rootSchema,
                        null, // We don't use dictionary encoding.
                        stream.getChannel)
  // Write everything to file...
  fileWriter.start()
  fileWriter.writeBatch()
  fileWriter.end()
  stream.close()
}
```

With the above I'm able to save a CSV to file. I checked everything went well by reading it and converting it to a CSV again, and the content is unchanged.

Note that the `ComplexWriterImpl` allows to write columns of different types, something that will come in handy to avoid storing number columns as strings.

<sub>(I'm playing with the reading side of things for now, this things will probably deserve their own SO questions.)</sub>

Comment: github links are dead

Comment: Thanks. Should be fixed.